# More than one submit button

Tags: php, button, submit

I'm having trouble with more then one submit Buttons in HTML & PHP, i tried to code a GUI for a web-based calculator. That's realy easy, but the function in php isn't so easy. So i have this simple GUI with 6 submit buttons:

```
<?php 
$output= isset($_POST['output']) ? $_POST['output'] : "";

function calc(){
//calculate...
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Calc</title>
<style type="text/css">
 .bwidth {
      width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="calc.php">
        <h1>
            <u>MY Own Calculator</u>
        </h1>
        <table border="3px" type="box" cellspacing="5px" width="250px">
            <tr style="height: 24px;">
                <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="<?php $ausgabe ?>"
                    value="0" style="width: 98%;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="1" value="1" /></td>
                <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="2" value="2" /></td>
                <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="3" value="3" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="minus" value="-" /></td>
                <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="plus" value="+" /></td>
                <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="enter"
                    value="=" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Now how I can differentiate these many submit buttons? It's even possible to have more than one submit button? I tried it to seperate the buttons by the value... but it didn't work.

And sb has an idea how i can add a value to an existing value in the textfield? So i can push button 1 and it will write 1 in the textfield and when i will push button 2 it will add the number 2 so it will a "12"?

Thanks for all suggestions!

Comment: I think what you really need is few normal button, and a javascript method.

Comment: Yeah, I'd second that. You don't need php to write this, just turn all the buttons to type="button" and use jquery/javascript to write the functions that support the buttons. Also, add ids to all form elements so that you can call them from the javascript using the id's as references.

Comment: The problem is I must write it in php, I need it for school.

Comment: Is it possible to give every submit-button a ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to verify which button is set using `isset($_GET['input_name'])`.

Or you could name different the inputs:

```
<form action="calc.php">
    <h1>
        <u>MY Own Calculator</u>
    </h1>
    <table border="3px" type="box" cellspacing="5px" width="250px">
        <tr style="height: 24px;">
            <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="<?php $ausgabe ?>"
                value="0" style="width: 98%;" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="digit" value="1" /></td>
            <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="digit" value="2" /></td>
            <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="digit" value="3" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="operation" value="-" /></td>
            <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="operation" value="+" /></td>
            <td><input class="bwidth" type="submit" name="operation" value="=" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And in your function:

```
function calc(){
    $op = isset($_GET['operation']) ? $_GET['operation'] : null;
    switch ($op) {
       case "+": .... ; break;
       case "-": .... ; break;
       case "=": .... ; break;
       default: "not supported";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

**In your php**

```
if(isset($_POST['minus'])) {
  // selected minus
}

if(isset($_POST['plus'])) {
  // selected plus
}

if(isset($_POST['enter'])) {
  // selected enter
}
```

When you click on a button its going to be send with your post data to the server. All the post data you find in the $_POST array.

If you want to look whats in the $_POST array you can run this small code:

```
<?php
   echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using JavaScript, first you will have to change your `<form>` to something like:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="calc.php">
```

Then the JavaScript and the buttons should look like this:

```
<script>
function submitForm(action)
{
    document.getElementById('form1').action = action;
    document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}
</script>

...

<input type="button" onclick="submitForm('page1.php')" value="submit 1" />
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm('page2.php')" value="submit 2" />
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you can use one name for all the submit buttons.

```
<input type="submit" name="operator" value="+" />
<input type="submit" name="operator" value="-" />
<input type="submit" name="operator" value="=" />
```

and you can get the values in php

```
<?php
    $opr = $_GET['operator'];
    if($opr == "+") {
         //do something
    } else if($opr == "-") {
         //do something
    } else if($opr == "=") {
         //do something
    }
?>
```

Comment: @Synoon - Can you please share a snippet of what you have tried. Also can you please try it once more after adding "method='get'" in form tag.

Answer (score 2):

when you submit the form to `calc.php`

Inside `calc.php` check which form element received.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['minus']))
{
    // minus is clicked
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['plus']))
{
    // plus is clicked
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['enter']))
{
    // enter is clicked
}
```

The clicked button will be sent with the form, not the others...

Hope it helps...

Comment: That is not always correct. I see some cases, when submit element name is not passed to server.

Comment: @MartinPerry - which cases?

Comment: Sometimes, when I confirm form with Enter. I think I see this behaviour in older IE.

Comment: @MartinPerry - Ok :-) Older versions of IE isn't always that good of keeping up to date with standards. Neither are the new ones :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have n number of submit buttons in a form.

Specify the action page in the same line as with the submit button.

```
<form action="actionpage.php">
<input type="submit" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="2" formaction="postPage.php">
</form>
```

UPDATED - IF ISSUES IN IE

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value="1" onclick="document.formName.action='abc.php';">
<input type="submit" value="2" onclick="document.formName.action='xyz.php';">
</form>
```

Comment: It would be cool if this worked... ...in ALL browsers. It only works in >=IE 10, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari. Of course it depends of the target users.

Comment: This should work in all browsers, i had worked long back. Never got negative feed back from clients ha ha ha... So try once as it is an attribute of input tag.

Comment: It's a HTML5-attribute, so it won't work in earlier versions of IE. Not negative feedback isn't always the same thing as "working everywhere" Take a look at: http://nostrongbeliefs.com/form-with-two-submit-buttons-using-html5/

Comment: hmmm....Then the best way to avoid the IE issues is to go with thie  onclick="document.formName.action='actionPage.php';"

Comment: Yes, that would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to submit your form. After clicking button, you call JS function that set some hidden element with pushed operation and then submit form to server.