# Is it possible to have two submit buttons in one form?

Tags: form-data, submit-button, prestashop-1.7

In Prestashop backoffice I have created a form with a submit button labelled as "Save".Is it possible to add another submit button with different action?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162972/more-than-one-submit-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More than one submit button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162972/more-than-one-submit-button)

Answer (score 2):

Just inspect `form.tpl` in `admin/themes/default/template/helpers/form/` there you'll find part

```smarty
{if isset($fieldset['form']['buttons'])}
  {foreach from=$fieldset['form']['buttons'] item=btn key=k}
    {if isset($btn.href) && trim($btn.href) != ''}
      <a href="{$btn.href}" {if isset($btn['id'])}id="{$btn['id']}"{/if} class="btn btn-default{if isset($btn['class'])} {$btn['class']}{/if}" {if isset($btn.js) && $btn.js} onclick="{$btn.js}"{/if}>{if isset($btn['icon'])}<i class="{$btn['icon']}" ></i> {/if}{$btn.title}</a>
    {else}
      <button type="{if isset($btn['type'])}{$btn['type']}{else}button{/if}" {if isset($btn['id'])}id="{$btn['id']}"{/if} class="btn btn-default{if isset($btn['class'])} {$btn['class']}{/if}" name="{if isset($btn['name'])}{$btn['name']}{else}submitOptions{$table}{/if}"{if isset($btn.js) && $btn.js} onclick="{$btn.js}"{/if}>{if isset($btn['icon'])}<i class="{$btn['icon']}" ></i> {/if}{$btn.title}</button>
    {/if}
  {/foreach}
{/if}
```

so as you see, you can define array of user defined buttons

```smarty
<button type="{if isset($btn['type'])}{$btn['type']}{else}button{/if}"...
```

wehere type can be 'submit' and if 'name' for your button defined, then in postProcess() you can do your stuff for your additional submit type button in hepler form.

f.e.

```php
public function renderForm() {

    $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
    $fields_form = array();

    $fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
        'legend' => array(
            ... legend part...
        ),
        'input' => array(
            ...arrays of inputs...
        ),
        'submit' => array(
            ...default submit button...
        ),
        'buttons' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'title' => $this->l('Whatever'),
                'name' => 'MySubmitName',
                'icon' => 'process-icon-back',
                'class' => 'pull-right',
            )
        )
    );

    $helper = new HelperForm();

    // Module, token and currentIndex
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminYourClassName');
    $helper->currentIndex = self::$currentIndex;

    // Language
    $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
    $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;

    // Title and toolbar
    $helper->show_toolbar = false;

    $helper->submit_action = 'submitWhatever';

    return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you need you should not bind multiple actions to the same Form Helper but simply specify a different name for each different submit input type defined for the Helper.